# External HDMI monitor needs mouse move to wake up

Tags: windows-7, hdmi, sleep

A Lenovo ThinkVision monitor connected via HDMI to a Toshiba Satellite R830 laptop (Windows 7) after waking the laptop from sleep does not display anything until the mouse is moved. The internal screen displays the image immediately. Windows is configured to give priority to the HDMI monitor, if it is connected.

What could be a cause? How to configure it as I want?

Comment: Is there a reason why you haven't upgraded the laptop to Windows 10? I think you'd be hard pressed to find a good troubleshooting path available to you on such an old OS. My thought process is your best bet is running the latest OS (Win10/11) and running windows updates so that you can benefit from the latest display and graphics drivers. If the problem still exists after that then perhaps it's a vendor specific issue with that monitor. I'd put this down as an answer but it's a mere suggestion at this point, because without you being on the latest OS there's no way to know what the issue is.

Comment: Yes, there are several strong reasons for that. Now to the question ...

Comment: What graphics does the machine have inside?

Comment: Intel HD Graphics

Comment: The guy asked what for a graphics my machine has, and then vanished. This is the typical situation. Ask only if you are able to help.